# Lumen API File Upload is not working

Tags: php, api, laravel-5, lumen

Problem is that , Request object is Returning Null when I am sending , Content-Type: multipart/form-data If I change the Content-Type to application/json is working like a charm, I want to get input file from Api Request . any suggestions??

Here is my code I am using Postman to call the service

```
 if( $request->file('image'))
           {
           $file = $request->file('image')->getClientOriginalName();
           $date = new DateTime();
           $d = $date->format('YmdHms').$file;
           $destinationPath ="images/";
           $request->file('image')->move($destinationPath, $d);
           }
           else 
           {
               $d = '';
           }

         $artistWork = ArtistWork::create([      
            'artist_id' => $request->input('artist_id'),    
            'image'=>$d,
                ]);
```

Using in Headers: 
 **Content-type:multipart/form-data**

Comment: Share javascript part ?

Comment: I am not using Javascript this is an API that i am calling from POSTMAN.

Comment: Postman is for test right ?

Comment: yes only for testing purpose

Comment: so why not you try/ask for dire js , why just for testing purpose. postman will not going to your project I think.

Comment: It will be use in Swift . not in Js

Comment: new version of postman (its an app now, not extension) with orange environment has a bug that cant upload file. the old one used html form to submit data. create a form and upload and check if it exist's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check your `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` directive in  `php.ini`

you cannot access uploaded files using the `file` method when `upload_max_filesize` is too small, magic variable `$_FILES` will be empty